# Are SIP URLs case-sensitive?

Tags: url, sip

I wonder whether SIP URLs and URL parameters, in particular, are case sensitive. Should the following URLs be considered equal:

```
<sip:123456789@domain.net;confid=1538A396CDE>
<sip:123456789@domain.net;confid=1538a396cde>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC3261 has the details on this, specifically [section 19.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-19.1.4):

> Comparison of the userinfo of SIP and SIPS URIs is case-
> sensitive.  This includes userinfo containing passwords or
> formatted as telephone-subscribers.  Comparison of all other
> components of the URI is case-insensitive unless explicitly
> defined otherwise.

From your example, it looks like they should be considered equivalent, however I would recommend consulting the RFC as there are examples where things should be treated as different by casing.